# Sed Scripting for beginners

Tags: sed

I have two commands I'd like to place in a `sed` script (to add some headings to a text file that's already been created). The two commands are as follows:

```
sed '/TEST/i\"-TEST-"\' grades.txt
sed '/PROJECT/i\"-PROJECT-"\' grades.txt
```

The problem I'm running into is creating the actual script. I start by typing `sed -f nameofscript.sed` at the command line. From there I type in an opening comment using `#`, hit enter, then type in my commands (without the grades.txt at the end). Every command I type is echo'd back to me. When I'm finished I again type `sed -f nameofscript.sed grades.txt`. Nothing seems to end the script. so I hit `control-d`. When I go to review the script (cat nameofscript.sed) there's nothing there. I've been at this for quite a while so any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Umm... sed is not an interactive text editor. You must write the script as you would any other text file, using the editor of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! As a newbie to UNIX the help is greatly appreciated. I'm so thankful I found this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a text editor to create a script file and then `sed -f nameofscript.sed` to execute that file.

`sed -f` does not start an interactive editor.

It runs `sed` over standard input (which is why it echos your lines back at you since it prints by default and you haven't given it any sed script to execute).

If `nameofscript.sed` didn't exist then `sed -f nameofscript.sed` would give you an error message about that when you tried to run it.

To be more explicit, when you run `sed -f some_empty_file.sed` you are telling `sed` to run an empty script over standard input. There is no standard input so `sed` waits and listens for input from your (via the keyboard). When you type into that "dead air" you are feeding `sed` content lines. It then processes those through its script (which is empty) and executes the default `print` action and spits them back out at you.

Comment: Gotcha! So I can just write the script using VIM, then type sed -f nameofscript.sed grades.txt to apply that file. I think I got it!

Comment: Yup; you've got it now.

Comment: Thanks again to those who helped me with my first script yesterday! I got everything working, and was able to execute it on the text file. Now I'm trying to send the edited version to a new text file, but having some problems. I'm typing: 

sed -f sedscriptname.sed grades.txt < grades_mod.txt

The command executes and runs, but when I open grades_mod.txt there's nothing in it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I think I got it, I used: sed -f mysedscript.txt <grades.txt >grades_mod.txt

Comment: @Chalmers Yes. `>` is redirect standard output. `<` is redirect standard input. `sed` takes a filename as well as reading from standard input so there's no reason to redirect the input (though it works as in your command) but you do need to redirect the output (if you want it in a file and not printed to screen).